# Storing simple data in android app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm making a simple GPA android app.  The user can input their grades and class names for each semester.  How would I then store each of these semesters so that they can always be pulled up in the app?  I might also need to store random variables that are alone.

I've briefly looked at options such as Shared Preferences, Internal Storage, and others.  What option is the best for my needs?  Please explain why.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any of them? You also have external storage , sqlite , cloud... SharedPreferences is easiest to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Explanation...

**Shared preferences** are good for storing ... an application's preferences, and other small bits of data. It's a just really simple persistent string key store for a few data types: boolean, float, int, long and string. So for instance if my app had a login, I might consider storing the session key as string within SharedPreferences.

**Internal storage** is good for storing application data that the user doesn't need access to, because the user cannot easily access internal storage. Possibly good for caching, logs, other things. Anything that only the app intends to Create Read Update or Delete.

**External storage**. Great for the opposite of what I just said. The dropbox app probably uses external storage to store the user's dropbox folder, so that the user has easy access to these files outside the dropbox application, for instance, using the file manager.

**SQLite databases** are great whenever you a lot of structured data and a relatively rigid schema for managing it. Put in layman's terms, SQLite is like MySQL or PostgreSQL except instead of the database acting as a server daemon which then takes queries from the CGI scripts like php, it is simply stored in a .db file, and accessed and queried through a simple library within the application. While SQLite cannot scale nearly as big as the dedicated databases, it is very quick and convenient for smaller applications, like Android apps. I would use an SQLite db if I were making an app for aggregating and downloading recipes, since that kind of data is relatively structured and a database would allow for it to scale well. Databases are nice because writing all of your data to a file, then parsing it back in your own proprietary format it no fun. Then again, storing data in XML or JSON wouldn't be so bad.

**Network connection** refers to storing data on the cloud. HTTP or FTP file and content transfers through the java.net.* packages makes this happen.

```
  Considering this i suggest you to use Sqlite especially in your case.
```

Best luck

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your need, some times you use all options in the same app, 
for example : the best way to store grades and classes is using database, in android SqlLite database. 
and for storing some variables values like username and password you just need to use shared preferences.... at least this is my policy in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite will be the best for your scenario.

As you can create well formatted Tables with desired columns. Either you can use **[pre-developed](http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/12/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in.html)** database or you can **[create tables on the go](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)**.