# one way data storage between android app and cloud storage (File, DB)

Tags: android, security, google-cloud-storage

I have a app data storage question.

I want to store users game scores centrally where I can access and evaluate later on. So, this is just one way communication with minimal interactivity. App can user send and forget method.

According to this
[Storing simple data in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117016/storing-simple-data-in-android-app)
I have to use network connection option.

My questions are
1) How do I enable secure communication between the app and this storage (to avoid some one sending fake requests)

2) What are the best storage or DB services (File in Google drive)

Comment: You can use game leader board for game score store.
Reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613254/how-to-display-a-leaderboard-with-google-play-game-services

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I am still trying this out, is there a way to test this leader board concept without creating a paid Google developer account

Comment: Sorry i don't know. You find solution please share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Cloud Storage Client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) to upload the file into Google Cloud Storage. By that it will support resumable upload automatically in case the file size is large. Otherwise you can also use [Drive API Client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) to upload the file into drive from your App. I think you want to upload user specific score into the storage or drive. In that case, you need to use [OAuth2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/) to authenticate your application on behalf of user to store the data. By that you can prevent fake request because you are only allowing specific users who are playing the games.